Iframe Redirection and troubleshooting problems
Trouble Redirecting Iframe Content: Seeking Assistance
I am using tinysearch for local .html files search engine. The links work no problem with the basic demo setup.
So I wanted to indirectly superimpose the search bar over all searched pages with an iframe. So the iframe page loads and the search bar is still there.
The problem is I cannot get the redirection so when I click on a link from the results the iframe redirects to that page.
Nothing shows up in dev tools for console or networking - like nothing is happening when I click. I have tried many versions and this is my most up-to-date attempt.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Demo with Embedded Guest and Search Overlay</title>
    <style>
        #iframe-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 100vh; /* Full viewport height */
        }
        #search-container {
            position: fixed; /* Fixed position */
            top: 0px; /* 0 pixels down from the top */
            left: 260px; /* Start from pixel 260 on the left */
            width: 328px; /* Width of 336 pixels */
            background: transparent; /* Completely transparent background */
            padding: 0px;
            box-shadow: none; /* No box shadow */
            z-index: 1001; 
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 8%;
        }
        #search-input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            background-color: #3182CE; /* Standard blue color */
            color: #E5E7EB; /* Text color */
            border: 2px solid #3182CE; /* Standard blue border color */
            border-radius: 20px; /* More rounded corners */
            outline: none; /* Remove outline */
            transition: border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s; /* Smooth transition */
        }
        #search-input:hover,
        #search-input:focus {
            border-color: #2D9D2E; /* Matrix green color on hover/focus */
            background-color: #2D9D2E; /* Matrix green color on hover/focus */
            color: white; /* Text color on hover/focus */
        }
        #demo {
            width: 300px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
            height: 40px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
            font-size: 16px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
            padding: 5px; /* Adjust the padding as needed */
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add space below the search input */
        }
        #results {
            display: none; /* Initially hide the results container */
            position: fixed;
            top: 80px; /* 80 pixels down from the top */
            left: 260px; /* Start from pixel 260 on the left */
            width: 336px; /* Width of 336 pixels */
            height: 290px; /* Height of 250 pixels */
            padding: 10px 20px;
            max-height: 340px; /* Adjust maximum height as needed */
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: #1A1A1B; /* Background color */
            border: 2px solid #374151; /* Border color */
            border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
            list-style-type: none; /* Remove bullet points */
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            color: #E5E7EB; /* Text color */
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        /* Style for the individual result items */
        #results li {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        /* Style for the result item link */
        #results li a {
            color: #E5E7EB; /* Text color */
            text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
        }
        /* Style for the result item link on hover */
        #results li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline; /* Underline on hover */
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Add the base element to redirect outbound links from iframe to parent -->
    <base target="_parent">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search-container">
        <input type="text" id="demo" onfocus="showResults()" onblur="hideResults()" onkeyup="doSearch()">
        <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="iframe-container">
        <iframe id="guest-iframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
        import { search, default as init } from './tinysearch_engine.js';
        window.search = search;

        async function run() {
            await init('./tinysearch_engine_bg.wasm');
        }
        run();
    </script>
    <script>
  function showResults() {
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideResults() {
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
}

function updateIframeAndRedirectParent(url) {
    console.log('updateIframeAndRedirectParent called with URL:', url);
    document.getElementById('guest-iframe').src = url; // Update the src attribute of the iframe
}

function doSearch() {
    let value = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    console.log(`Search query: ${value}`);

    const results = search(value, 12);
    console.log(`Results: ${results}`);

    let ul = document.getElementById('results');
    ul.innerHTML = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        let [title, url] = results[i];
        let elemlink = document.createElement('a');
        elemlink.innerHTML = title;
        elemlink.href = url; // Set the href attribute to the URL directly
        elemlink.setAttribute('onclick', `updateIframeAndRedirectParent('${url}'); return false;`); // Set onclick attribute to call updateIframeAndRedirectParent function and prevent default link behavior
        li.appendChild(elemlink);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>

